# java , using JsonObject parse a strange json string

Tags: java, json

with JsonObject  (com.google.gson.JsonObject)

I´m having problems accessing  each element like "alfa-romeo" or "aston-martin" to get the values of the property´s "pt" and "en" from "alfa-romeo" and "aston-martin"

{"options":{"alfa-romeo":{"pt":"Alfa Romeo","en":"Alfa Romeo"},"aston-martin":{"pt":"Aston Martin","en":"Aston Martin"}}}

I using this code to access "options" but with no success
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(strJson).getAsJsonObject();

JsonArray arr = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("options");

where I´m getting :
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonArray

can any one advise me ?
Thank you
Roque

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to get an array instead of an object:

options = `{"alfa-romeo":{"pt":"Alfa Romeo","en":"Alfa Romeo"},"aston-martin":{"pt":"Aston Martin","en":"Aston Martin"}}`

is an object and not an array.

```
JsonArray arr = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("options");
```

should be:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = hello.getAsJsonObject("options");
```

PS: You might want to upgrade to a newer version of Gson, your methods are deprecated

Comment: thank you .. but how can I access "alfa-romeo" or ""aston-martin" .. I just don´t know the names of all "element´s" that are inside of "options " ... thank you again

Comment: there is a way to loop thru each element  ? using other json lib ?

Comment: Yes you can call ".entrySet()" on (in my example) jsonObject and if you want it as an array call additionally .toList()